# Что значит «sh: 1: -t: not found» в [error_log] XAMPP'а

Tags: email, xampp

Установил XAMPP. Разбираюсь с настройкой почты. Для начала просто запустил PHP-функцию `mail()`:

```
mail('mail@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message');
```

и заглянул в [error_log] сервера; там появилась такая запись:

`sh: 1: -t: not found`

Я только понимаю, что `sh` — shell, а что значит остальное и почему оно не найдено?

Comment: если почитаете ответы к этому вопросу http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost то сразу поймете, что такое -t.

Скорее всего Вам нужно просто правильно прописать свою программу, которая отправляет почту.

Comment: Я уже перечитал кучу инфы и перепробовал в два раза больше, но что-то ничего не выходит и вопросов тьма ... У меня Ubuntu, а слова «sendmail» вообще в системе нет :) . Короче каша. По мне, так такие мометы должны быть решены на уровне ОС, а не дополнительных приложений и т. п. Буду разбираться с самого начала ...

Comment: Здесь http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/xampp есть ответ на Ваш вопрос. Но ставить xampp на Линукс... как минимум некрасиво и небезопасно. Все и так есть в репозитория. Это же не винда.

Comment: Вы несомненно правы насчёт «Но ставить xampp на Линукс... как минимум некрасиво и небезопасно». Спасибо за наставление: поставил всё «родное», пришлось всё же помучатся с `sendmail`, с которым я так и не разобрался по вопросу FQDN — поэтому настроил всё через `msmtp`. Вот, отличная статья: [digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP пытается выполнить команду, которой был передан аргумент `-t`, например для отправки почты php использует sendmail :

```
   sendmail_path    "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Просто проверьте ваши настройки в php.ini , где у вас лишний или неправильно записанный аргумент `-t`в sh-команде.